# ctx.stroke() takes up to 8,7s on mac, but less than 1ms in any other browser

Tags: javascript, macos, performance, canvas, safari

I have a canvas creating 8 images (colored google map markers):
[image]
This code is the one posing problems:

```
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo( lw, h/3 )       //  Left
ctx.lineTo( w/2, lw )       //  Top
ctx.lineTo( w - lw, h/3 )   //  Right
ctx.lineTo( w/2, h - lw )   //  Bottom
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fill()
// conditional dashed line border (see in codepen L31 - L41)
ctx.fill()
ctx.stroke()    //  This call takes up to 8.7sec (on MAC safari only)
```

I have tried to narrow the code to the problem only, but just to be sure I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Akxe/pen/wMNKow).
Proof, that it does not work on MAC

[image]

How to make it work on MAC as fast as on PC?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to make it work on MAC as fast as on PC? PS: added edit, thought it was obvious but maybe not...

Comment: Could be machine and browser dependent. Have you tried one more than one mac and more than one browser??? If it is just machine or browser then you should create an alternative solution for those setups

Comment: for info, your codepen crashes my FF 45 on osx 10.9

Comment: @Kaiido you were right it was Firefox not Safari I have found the solution to it thought

Comment: @Blindman67 it was affecting multiple Mac with Firefox, I have posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is wrong, don't know if it should be reported or not...
The thing is, that Firefox on Mac (and maybe even on others), have problems with `ctx.setLineDash([0])` other browsers don't have problems with zero in it, but Firefox does for the first stroke call.

The "correct" way to do it is `ctx.setLineDash([])`.